# Initializing cells and variables in worksheet when file is opened

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to initialize worksheet variables and cells on opening file? I have some cells which needs to be initiated and some variables also in my code.

I have found a way to initialize cells using the `workbook_open` sub. But initializing variables (defined in sheet1) is not possible. Is there an equivalent of `Userform_Initialize` for worksheets? I don't want to use `worksheet_activate` as I need this to perform only once. Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Public variable**
If you declare a public variable in sheet1

```
Public strA As String
```

then you can set a value in `Workbook_Open()` with

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").strA = "init" 
Sheet1.strA = "init" 'Alternative … If you prefer the VBA name of the sheet
```

---

**Private variable**
If it is a private variable then you need a init sub within sheet1 which you call from `Workbook_Open()`

sheet1

```
Private strA As String

Sub MyInit()
    strA = "init"
End Sub
```

workbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").MyInit
    Sheet1.MyInit 'Alternative … If you prefer the VBA name of the sheet
End Sub
```